# Помогите доработать код для бота Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Помогите доработать код бота на Python с помощью библиотеки aiogram.
Бот должен заносить введённый пользователем пароль в БД

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def password_vvod(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль:')
    conn = sqlite3.connect("patient.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO wow(password) VALUES (?)''', (message.chat.id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

примерно таким образом должно работать

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, types
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db") 
cursor = conn.cursor()
 
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE users
                  (user_id text, password text,)
               """)
conn.commit()   
           
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def password_vvod(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль:')
    conn = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)", (message.chat.id,message.text))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Введённые данные в таблице не появляются, хотя ошибок нет

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно причина в том что вы используете
`message.chat.id`
А надо:
`message.from_chat.id`